# Python: retrieving a "hidden" element using bs4.soup.find

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

for my mini-project: I'm trying to create a simple, very basic scraper that checks for the availability of a retail item.

website of interest: https://doobydobap.com/shop/dymy-t-shirt-white

I'm trying to extract the text data from the `stock out-of-stock` p-class in the code. [here is how it looks in the source code btw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdNWw.png) vs. what i was able to grab using the parent div (which was visible) and went from there, but it [still turned out to be invisible...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THyLi.png)

> the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'`

my code:

```
`availability = soup.find('p', {'class': 'stock out-of-stock'}).get_text().lower()`
```

the expected outcome: soup.find should be extracting the text data 'Out of stock' but it's having trouble.

I think the **problem** is that the code block in question is greyed out by default because the user has to select a t-shirt size before the div/span element appears in the code. by default, the 'choose option' drop-down makes the target class element in question invisible.

hope that made sense. I could be wrong, but that's how I understand the situation. is there any way to solve this invisibility problem? I know the limitation that bs4 cannot interact with browsers obv because it is a parser, but I wanted to ask.

I appreciate any help my way!

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

Information is as mentioned provided dynamically by `JavaScript` and request could not render it, so wont get it directly.

#### How to get information?

To get the available information for all variations you could select the form that holds the data and load it as json:

```
json.loads(soup.select_one('form[data-product_variations]')['data-product_variations'])
```

#### Example

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://doobydobap.com/shop/dymy-t-shirt-white')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

json.loads(soup.select_one('form[data-product_variations]')['data-product_variations'])
```

#### Output

```
[{'attributes': {'attribute_pa_size': 'xsmall'}, 'availability_html': '<p class="stock out-of-stock">Out of stock</p>\n', 'backorders_allowed': False, 'dimensions': {'length': '', 'width': '', 'height': ''}, 'dimensions_html': 'N/A', 'display_price': 35, 'display_regular_price': 35, 'image': {'title': 'DYMY T Shirt', 'caption': '', 'url': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645.jpg', 'alt': '', 'src': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-1200x1200.jpg?crop=1', 'srcset': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-1200x1200.jpg?crop=1 1200w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-640x640.jpg?crop=1 640w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-100x100.jpg?crop=1 100w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-300x300.jpg 300w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-150x150.jpg?crop=1 150w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-768x768.jpg 768w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-530x530.jpg?crop=1 530w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-750x750.jpg 750w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-500x500.jpg?crop=1 500w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-800x800.jpg?crop=1 800w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-400x400.jpg?crop=1 400w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-200x200.jpg?crop=1 200w', 'sizes': '(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px', 'full_src': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645.jpg', 'full_src_w': 4123, 'full_src_h': 4123, 'gallery_thumbnail_src': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-100x100.jpg?crop=1', 'gallery_thumbnail_src_w': 100, 'gallery_thumbnail_src_h': 100, 'thumb_src': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-640x640.jpg?crop=1', 'thumb_src_w': 640, 'thumb_src_h': 640, 'src_w': 1200, 'src_h': 1200}, 'image_id': 11660, 'is_downloadable': False, 'is_in_stock': False, 'is_purchasable': True, 'is_sold_individually': 'no', 'is_virtual': False, 'max_qty': '', 'min_qty': 1, 'price_html': '', 'sku': 'DYMY-TSHIRT-WHITE', 'variation_description': '', 'variation_id': 12148, 'variation_is_active': True, 'variation_is_visible': True, 'weight': '', 'weight_html': 'N/A'}, {'attributes': {'attribute_pa_size': 'small'}, 'availability_html': '<p class="stock out-of-stock">Out of stock</p>\n', 'backorders_allowed': False, 'dimensions': {'length': '', 'width': '', 'height': ''}, 'dimensions_html': 'N/A', 'display_price': 35, 'display_regular_price': 35, 'image': {'title': 'DYMY T Shirt', 'caption': '', 'url': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645.jpg', 'alt': '', 'src': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-1200x1200.jpg?crop=1', 'srcset': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-1200x1200.jpg?crop=1 1200w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-640x640.jpg?crop=1 640w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-100x100.jpg?crop=1 100w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-300x300.jpg 300w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-150x150.jpg?crop=1 150w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-768x768.jpg 768w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-530x530.jpg?crop=1 530w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-750x750.jpg 750w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-500x500.jpg?crop=1 500w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-800x800.jpg?crop=1 800w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-400x400.jpg?crop=1 400w, https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-200x200.jpg?crop=1 200w', 'sizes': '(max-width: 1200px) 100vw, 1200px', 'full_src': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645.jpg', 'full_src_w': 4123, 'full_src_h': 4123, 'gallery_thumbnail_src': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-100x100.jpg?crop=1', 'gallery_thumbnail_src_w': 100, 'gallery_thumbnail_src_h': 100, 'thumb_src': 'https://doobydobap.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Capture0007-şiğç-56290412-1631989117645-640x640.jpg?crop=1', 'thumb_src_w': 640, 'thumb_src_h': 640, 'src_w': 1200, 'src_h': 1200}, 'image_id': 11660, 'is_downloadable': False, 'is_in_stock': False, 'is_purchasable': True, 'is_sold_individually': 'no', 'is_virtual': False, 'max_qty': '', 'min_qty': 1, 'price_html': '', 'sku': 'DYMY-TSHIRT-WHITE', 'variation_description': '', 'variation_id': 12149, 'variation_is_active': True, 'variation_is_visible': True, 'weight': '', 'weight_html': 'N/A'},...]
```